# Probability of rolling a number from 1 to 4 exactly once with 3 identical dice.

Tags: probability

> In a game, a player selects one number from $1, 2, 3$ or $4$ and rolls
>   three standard dice. What is the probability that his chosen number
>   appears on exactly one of the dice?

Even though the player cannot chose from all numbers on the dice $(1$ to $6)$, I think this should not have any impact on the probability of rolling the chosen number, since whatever number, $n$, he choses will theoretically show up $\frac{1}{6}^{\textrm{th}}$ of the time. It also seems that the order of the numbers on the dice should not matter for the dice which don't have the chosen number. Therefore, from what I understand, only the following three distinct possible rolls could occur so that the chosen number appears exactly once.

$$n \quad a \quad b$$
$$a \quad n \quad b$$
$$a \quad b \quad n$$

Where $a, b \in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$. Therefore, the probability should be

$$\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times 3 = \frac{25}{72}$$

But apparently the answer is $\frac{27}{64}$, which I can't understand.

Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You did the correct computations for a six sided dice (a cube). The result you saw is for a [**four** sided dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-sided_die), a (tetrahedron).

Comment: So you're saying the books wrong? You questioning the book?? =)

Comment: Yup! :) Instead of "standard dice" they should have said "four sided dice" (or something like that) otherwise the book should have said $25/72$ or $75/216$.

Comment: Alright cool, thanks for freeing my mind.

Comment: You're welcome.